# MySQL Group By and Order by not playing nicely together

Tags: mysql

I have read a few post on this, but not seeming to be able to fix my problem.

I am calling two database queries to populate two array's that run along side by side of each other, but they aren't matching, as the order that they come out is different. I believe i have something to do with the Group By, and this may require a sub query, but again a little lost...

Query 1:

```
SELECT count(bids_bid.total_bid), bidtime_bid, users_usr.company_usr, users_usr.id_usr 
FROM bids_bid 
INNER JOIN users_usr 
ON bids_bid.user_bid = users_usr.id_usr 
WHERE auction_bid = 36 
GROUP BY user_bid 
ORDER BY bidtime_bid ASC
```

Query 2:

```
SELECT auction_bid, user_bid, bidtime_bid, bids_bid.total_bid 
FROM bids_bid 
WHERE auction_bid = 36  
ORDER BY bidtime_bid ASC
```

Even though the 'Order by' is the same the results aren't matching. The users are coming out in a different sequence.

I hope this makes sense, and thanks in advance.

*** Update ***
I just wanted to add a bit of clarity on what the output I want is. I need to only show 1 result by one user (user_bid) the second query show all users rows. I only need the first one to show the first row entered for each user. So if I could order before the the group and by min date, that would be ace...

Comment: add bidtime_bid, users_usr.company_usr, users_usr.id_usr into group by too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I was complicating issues that I didn't need to. The solution I found was before.

```
SELECT users_usr.company_usr, 
    users_usr.id_usr, 
    bids_bid.bidtime_bid, min(bidtime_bid) as minbid FROM bids_bid INNER JOIN users_usr ON bids_bid.user_bid = users_usr.id_usr
WHERE auction_bid = 36
GROUP BY id_usr
ORDER BY minbid ASC
```

Thanks everyone for making me look (try) harder...

Answer (score 3):

It's to be expected. You're fetching fields that are NOT involved in the grouping, and are not part of an aggregate function. MySQL allows such things, but generally the results of the ungrouped/unaggregated functions can be wonky.

Because MySQL is free to chose WHICH of the potentially multiple 'free' rows to choose for the actual result row, you will get different results. Generally it picks the first-encountered 'free choice' result, but that's not defined/guaranteed.

Comment: To explain it another way, grouping "bunches up" your query into clumps, so it has to know what field or fields to use to collapse on, which is what GROUP BY is for.

Comment: Thanks Marc, how would I order the first query to match the second?

Comment: Force both to sort by the same specs. if the username is relevant, then add it to the sort-by clause.

Comment: Getting more and more confused :) I need to only show 1 result by one user (user_bid) the second query show all users rows. I only need the first one to show the first row entered for each user.

Answer (score 0):

You use grouping when you  want unique results in result set according to some
group id (column name). usually grouping is used with  aggregate functions such as 
(min, max,count,sum..).

Ordering or inner query is nothing to do with result set, i suggest read some introductory
tutorials about grouping  and think/treat Sql as a set based language  and most of the set theory is applied on sql you'll be fine.